How do I detect and fix overlapping geometry in 3d text
I'm creating a text object for use in a boolean modifier but I'm having trouble because the letters are overlapping, causing the modifier to fail:

Because the overlapping vertices are all exactly on the faces of the next letter "Select interior faces" doesn't find the issue
Is there any way to detect this happening and is there a way to programmatically merge the overlapping geometry together?
